# How to solve neural network accuracy become constant issue?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am using some simple model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=len(allKeys), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(31, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(N, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=500, batch_size=40)
```

X.shape (31, 147)
Y.shape (31, 13)

the values in X are either 0 or some under lower than 1.0. 
Y, is sparse array, one column in one row is 1, the rest columns are 0.

The acc is always lower than 0.25. Most time it just 0.12. If I add dropout layer, I see the acc values change, but not above 0.25, most time just gave worse result.

Epoch 290/500
31/31 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 9.6283 - acc: 0.1290
Epoch 291/500
31/31 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 9.6283 - acc: 0.1290
Epoch 292/500
31/31 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 9.6283 - acc: 0.1290

---------------------------- Updated code ------------------------------

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=len(allKeys), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(31, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(N, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.3, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
one_hot_labels = to_categorical(Y, num_classes=N)

model.fit(X, one_hot_labels, epochs=100, batch_size=40)
```

Comment: Is this network doing regression or classification? And how many classes in case of classification?

Comment: If you have 8 classes, the accuracy its theoreticaly zero because it might be firing the same one everytime, try plotting activation histograms and distributions in tensorboard. What is input? It may be too hard for this architecture.

Comment: Updated the code, 1. Use step 0.001. 2. Tried with/without dropout. 3. Changed the last step from relu to softmax. 4. Used to_category. Still got the same result;

Comment: Re: Matias: This is for classfication. There are totally 13 cases.

Comment: Re: Josef: tensorboard is interesting!! I am wondering whether I can use it for keras. Seems tensorboard is using tensorflow.session(), I don't know how to access it from keras.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the row

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

you intend to do classification. If this is the case, you need to change

```
model.add(Dense(N, activation='relu'))
```

into

```
model.add(Dense(N, activation='softmax'))
```

Also, make sure that the Y vector is a one-hot vector. You can use keras [to_categorical](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) function for this purpose.

Comment: I tried to change all the activation from relu to softmax, as well as some relu to softmax. The result are the same. Please see my updated code.

Comment: @BlueDolphin Does Y a 1-hot vector? or is one_hot_labels a 1-hot vector? could you include s sample of the elements from Y?

Comment: @BlueDolphin Don't change all the activations to softmax, keep the ReLU activations and use softmax only at the last layer. This should work. Make sure that your labels are one-hot encoded.

Comment: I tried both scenario, results are the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with learning rate. I looks like default value is too high for this case.

Comment: Tried with 0.001 as learning rate, still got low accuracy. 0.064.  See updated code.